# Yii2: Adding menubar specific content to menubar on specific page load

Tags: yii2

I am having two layouts main.php & builder.php out of which main.php is the vertical one & is having profile features. I want to add another content into main.php when view-:'vendor.php' loads. That content is specific to only vendor view. How to do that???

Or is it possible that i can hide that one in the main.php & can show that on vendor load only???

Answer (score 0):

several options:
1) create a new layout that you include only for that controller or action
2) there is always the params section. If you think about it in all your views you have

```
$this->title = 'Create Product';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

and in the layout you have

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
]) ?>
```

so you can do in the view a

```
$this->params['whatever'] = "Hello World";
```

And then in the layout have a

```
if(isset($this->params['whatever'])) echo $this->params['whatever']
```